# Webpack V4 loader issue

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I am getting error while compiling my scss file using webpack.
I am currently using webpack v4. Webpack shows

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Error.
help me to fix this issue. here is my project structure , error and package,json

[image]

This is the directory structure.

[image]

My `package.json` file

[image]

The Error while running webpack

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry:path.resolve(__dirname,'resources/assets/js/entry.js'),
  output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,'public/js'),
    filename:'script.bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    rules:[{
      test: /\.(s*)css$/,
      use:ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback:'style-loader',
        use:[{
              loader:"css-loader",
              options:{
                url:false
              }
            },
            {
              loader:"sass-loader"
            }]
      })
    }]
  },
  plugins:[
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try test for `/\.(s*)css$/`? And I do not think you need to add `""` to the regex expr

Comment: @RuChernChong, got error ------  TypeError: Path must be a string. Received /\.(s*)css$/

Comment: Try `test: /\.(s*)scss$/,` You can add the path.resolve in the options

Comment: @RuChernChong, even with " ", still the same error.

Comment: @RuChernChong, scss got compiled but got that now.. edited question plz. check

Comment: Do you have a `entry.js`? Problem is on this line `entry: path.resolve(__dirname,'resources/assets/js/entry.js'),`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168034/discussion-between-ru-chern-chong-and-chandra-shekhar).